# Access Delete Query Deleting Tables on Multiple Databases

Tags: ms-access

I am using access 2007. In the database I am using a delete query to remove data from a table. What shocks me is that even though I have create multiple duplicates of the database in several different locations and with different names on the same server PC, the minute I run the delete query it removes all other tables on the other databases which I do not wish for as they are backups.

Could someone please help to explain why my delete query is not limiting itself to one database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. The database was broken up into a back and front end. Making duplicates of the front end still was linked to the original back end. Had to copy over tables from back end to front end to make the database a single entity again.